# Overlapping Transparent Views in a Prism Region

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I was wondering if there is a way to show two overlapping transparent views in one named Region? My example below shows two overlapped transparent views in their own separate named region container in the first grid row. In the second grid row we have one named region "RegionC". The first registered view is the one that is displayed ("ViewA"). Am I correct that if we have multiple views registered to a region then we can only show one view at a time? Is there a way to show two overlapped views in one named Region? Or is it standard practice to add another content control to support multiple views shown? One reason why I want to do this is so I can better separate my XAML code in separate views and inject them into one region container as needed.

ShellWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PrismDemo.Views.ShellWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Title="{Binding Title}" Height="150" Width="325" >
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionA" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionB" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionC" />
</Grid>
```

ShellWindow.xaml.cs

```
using Prism.Regions;
using System.Windows;

namespace PrismDemo.Views
{
    public partial class ShellWindow : Window
    {
        public ShellWindow(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RegionA", typeof(ViewA));
            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RegionB", typeof(ViewB));
            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RegionC", typeof(ViewA));
            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RegionC", typeof(ViewB));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewA.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="PrismDemo.Views.ViewA"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrismDemo.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="300">
<TextBlock Text="ViewA" FontSize="20" />
```

ViewB.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="PrismDemo.Views.ViewB"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrismDemo.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="300">
<TextBlock Text="ViewB" FontSize="30" />
```

Comment: Use `ItemsControl` instead of `ContentControl` for `RegionC`.

Comment: I tried that but it just stacks the views vertically and doesn't actually overlap them.

Comment: Set the `ItemsPanel` property to `Grid` on the `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Yes, that does it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ItemsControl` instead of `ContentConrol` for your region `RegionC` and set its `ItemsPanel` to `Grid`.

Here is the XAML:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionC">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct that if we have multiple views registered to a region then we can only show one view at a time?

For regions in a `ContentControl`, yes, you are correct, because it can only have one `Content` at a time. But basically any control can host a region (provided you create an associated `regionAdapter`), for example, an `ItemsControl` or a `TabControl` can have multiple views inside them at the same time.

> Is there a way to show two overlapped views in one named Region?

Yes, if you provide a `RegionAdapter` for a `Grid`, for example.

> Or is it standard practice to add another content control to support multiple views shown?

Yes and no. Standard for multiple views in multiple regions, not standard for multiple views in the same region.